# Undefined control sequence \affiliation [1]{organization={

Tags: overleaf, arxiv, els-cas

I am using the cas-dc document class, and it compiles on Overleaf without any errors. But I got the following error when I submitted it to arxiv:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.89 \affiliation
[1]{organization={ABC},
?
! Emergency stop.
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Is this definitely the first error the arXiv compiler gives? Are you sure your code compiles without error on Overleaf (make sure to check the raw logs carefully).  Otherwise we may need a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) which reproduces the error, or copies of the full log(s).